Your app currently targets API level 23 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure
Your app currently targets API level 23 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance.
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        googlePlayServicesVersion= "21.0.1"
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

        googlePlayServicesIidVersion = "17.0.0" // default: "17.0.0" - AndroidX
        firebaseIidVersion = "19.0.1" // default: "19.0.1"

    }

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.bikaneredge"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bikaneredge"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 3
        versionName '1.0.2'
    }


I have the same issue. I changed the minSdkVersion from 23 to 24 and it said I was targetting 24, so it was definitely incorrectly picking up the min as the target.
